# How can I add a secondary group to the user of the docker container with ddev?

Tags: ddev

When starting a container through a ddev project, the user id and primary group id are replicated from the host into the container. How can I also replicate the group ids for the secondary groups in the container? I believe this is done with the `--group-add` parameter in docker, but I am not sure how to use that parameter from within ddev.

`ddev version` returns:

DDEV version     v1.22.2

docker           24.0.5

docker-compose   v2.21.0

docker-platform  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

I am running a drupal project on ddev under account userA in dir:

`/home/userA/drupal`

The contents of `/home/userA/drupal/.ddev/docker-compose.mounts.yaml` are:

```
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - /media/userB/resources:/var/www/html/private:rw
```

The intention is to be able to write to `/media/userB/resources` from the drupal instance.

On the host `id` gives:

```
uid=1000(userA) gid=1003(userA) groups=1003(userA),1008(userB)
```

and the `resources` dir has group write permissions, so this works: `touch /media/userB/resources/test`

From within the container, I managed to create a group with the correct group id with: `groupadd -r userB -g 1008`. I then tried to add the container user to it with: `usermod -a -G userB userA`, but that does not seem to work.

In the container `id` gives:

```
uid=1000(userA) gid=1003(userA) groups=1003(userA)
```

so this does not work: `touch /var/www/html/private/test`.

The account for userB is a dummy account and all users have access to it, the setup is isolated from the web and I am running ddev as a mini production solution.

Just adding another observation: userA on host can touch files within the mounted dir and outside it. userA on container can touch files only outside the mounted dir. userA on container cannot delete a file in the mounted directory created by userA while on host.

Comment: If your problem is permissions when mounting directories, you'll have to talk about what OS you're on and and what Docker provider you're using. But it's unlikely that adding groups inside the container will resolve this class of problems.  The problem is the permissions on the host I would think. Anyway, you'll want to give full info about the host-side permissions.

Comment: Good point, I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and ddev 1.22.2  - also updated the question. Also, user A can write in user's B directory on the host.

Comment: You're not using Docker Desktop for Linux are you? (please don't)

Comment: If you can show the directory(ies) (on the host) that you want to mount with full path, that will help. If you can link to your `docker-compose.*.yaml` you're trying to use to do the mounting, that will help too. Probably gist.github.com.

Mostly, you're doing something very complex for no reason that anybody will be able to understand. How is this going to work on production?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read the question. No, I am not using Docker Desktop. I have updated the question with the `docker-compose.*.yaml` contents. I am sure I have over-complicated this, so any pointers to simplify it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rfay for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77146265/how-can-i-add-a-secondary-group-to-the-user-of-the-docker-container-with-ddev/77154587?noredirect=1#comment136054291_77154587) which led to this answer:

Add a new yaml file:

`/home/userA/drupal/.ddev/docker-compose.groups.yaml`

with contents:

```yaml
services:
    web:
        group_add:
            - userB
```

then restart ddev and check permissions in the container:

`uid=1000(userA) gid=1003(userA) groups=1003(userA),1008(userB)`

and files can be touched in userB's directory.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any complexity in this, although I was surprised to see docker mount with a different group name than I expected. I used Ubuntu 22.04 and DDEV v1.22.3, and Docker 24.0.6 although any Debian/Ubuntu and any DDEV version and any recent Docker would have had the same results.

- The directory you want to share needs to have group read and write permissions on the *host*. In my case I'm mounting the directory `/media/junk`  which has a few files in it. The directory and all files are owned by `junk` and group `junk`:

```
rfay@ub-2204:~$ ls -lR /media/junk
/media/junk:
total 0
rfay@ub-2204:~$ ls -lR /media/junk
/media/junk:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 junk junk 0 Sep 21 20:17 four.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 junk junk 0 Sep 21 20:15 one.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 junk junk 0 Sep 21 20:17 three.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 junk junk 0 Sep 21 20:15 two.txt
```

- Now mount the files into your project. I used a variant of your `docker-compose.mounts.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - /media/junk:/var/www/html/private:rw
```

- `ddev restart`
- Now when you `ddev ssh` and `cd /var/www/html/private` you will see this:

```
rfay@ub-2204:~/workspace/d9$ ddev ssh
rfay@d9-web:/var/www/html$ cd private/
rfay@d9-web:/var/www/html/private$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 rfay 0 Sep 22 02:17 four.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 rfay 0 Sep 22 02:15 one.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 rfay 0 Sep 22 02:17 three.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 rfay 0 Sep 22 02:15 two.txt

rfay@d9-web:/var/www/html/private$ ls -ltd .
drwxrwxr-x 2 1002 rfay 4096 Sep 22 02:17 .
r
```

```
rfay@d9-web:/var/www/html/private$ touch something.txt
rfay@d9-web:/var/www/html/private$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 rfay 0 Sep 22 02:17 four.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 rfay 0 Sep 22 02:15 one.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 rfay rfay 0 Sep 22 02:33 something.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 rfay 0 Sep 22 02:17 three.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 rfay 0 Sep 22 02:15 two.txt
```

I am able to touch a file inside the container without trouble.

I didn't make any changes at all to users inside the container.

Again, I don't think this is probably a great idea, and you'd be a lot better off just copying what you need off of that mount and using it from your own user.

Comment: Indeed this is the process I followed. I can touch a file on the host, but I get permission denied in the container. What does `id` return for you in the host and in the container?

Comment: `id -a` shows `$ id -a
uid=501(rfay) gid=20(dialout) groups=20(dialout)`

Comment: Is your /media/UserB a network share? If it is, it's a far more complex situation. You have BOTH network permissions and docker mount permissions to deal with.

Comment: No, the /media/userB is just a subdirectory in a different home folder for userB on the same machine (but different disk). Thank you for posting the output of id. Is that on the host? Why don't you have the `junk` group showing there?

Comment: Also note that I added another paragraph in the question: "userA on host can touch files within the mounted dir and outside it. userA on container can touch files only outside the mounted dir. userA on container cannot delete a file in the mounted directory created by userA while on host."

Comment: You say /media/userB is "just a subdirectory in a different home folder". That would be very unusual. A home directory is almost always in /home. Could you try it with another user (in the same group) that is in /home? Are both users in the same primary group? Unfortunately, since this is not a DDEV problem, and since I was already able to easily demonstrate it working correctly, I can't spend much more time on it. You can easily work on this by just using `docker run -it -v <volumemount> -u <uid>:<guid ubuntu bash` and fiddle with things until you understand it and can get what you want.

Comment: One thing I was going to mention: If you're not using a standard docker-ce installation please switch and use it. For example, if you're using rootless, go to normal install. Please use the strategy in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/docker-installation/#linux which is https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you for the time reading through the questions and comments @rfay . I am happy to explore it further, but just to come back to the original question, is there a way to use the docker `--group-add` parameter with ddev?

Comment: Docs are at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#group_add - you would do a `docker-compose.*.yaml` to add that. Maybe this will help you, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/custom-compose-files/#docker-composeyaml-examples

Comment: This fixed the problem. If you would like to post it as an answer, then I can mark it as accepted. Happy to do it as well if you do not have the time.

Comment: Do please post the answer! It's fine to answer your own question.